# Agrregation using mongoDBtemplate for Nested document

Tags: spring, mongodb, aggregation-framework, spring-mongodb

I am trying to use agrregation using spring mongodb template. The grouping has to be done on third level of document. input document is

```
{
    "_id": "59036b0fa036cc28c8e07db6",
    "sections": [{
        "srcName": "test1",
        "data": [{
                "srcKey": "",
                "rowIdx": 0,
                "values": [{
                        "srcDesc": "Assets"
                    },
                    {
                        "srcDesc": "NonAssets"
                    },
                    {
                        "srcDesc": "liabilities"
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "srcKey": "01",
                "rowIdx": 1,
                "values": [{
                    "srcDesc": "NonAssets"
                }]
            }
        ]
    }]
}
```

Essentially I want to run query like

```
select distinct(srcdesc) from document where srcName="test1";
```

Please see that srcDesc is third level of nesting. I am trying below java code

```
  private MatchOperation getMatchOPeration(String sectionName){
      Criteria criteira=Criteria.where("sectionName").in(sectionName);
      return match(criteira);
  }

  private GroupOperation getGroupOperaion(){
      return  group("srcDesc").last("srcDesc").as("srcDesc"); 
  }

 private ProjectionOperation  getProjectionOPeration(){
      return project("srcDesc").and("srcDesc").previousOperation();
  }

 public List<SourceName> findAllSourceNamesBySection(String sectionName){
       List<SectionsDocument> sourceNameList=new ArrayList<>();
       MatchOperation matchOPeration=getMatchOPeration(sectionName);
       GroupOperation groupOperation=getGroupOperaion();
       ProjectionOperation projectionOperation=getProjectionOPeration();
       AggregationResults<SectionsDocument> aggregationResults=
       mongoTemplate.aggregate(Aggregation.newAggregation(
            matchOPeration,
            unwind("sections.data.values"),
            groupOperation,
            projectionOperation),StatDocument.class,SectionsDocument.class);
            sourceNameList=aggregationResults.getMappedResults();   
       return new ArrayList<>();
  }
```

Comment: What is your mongo server and spring mongo version ?

Comment: @veeram ,I am using       <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
   <version>1.5.1.RELEASE</version><groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
   <version>1.5.1.RELEASE</version>

Comment: What is your mongo server version ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can update your code to below.

Added `$unwind` to unwind  `sections` & `sections.data` before unwinding `sections.data.values`.

Updated `$group` get distinct  `srcDesc` with `$addToSet` operator.

Removed the `$project` stage.

```
private  MatchOperation getMatchOperation(String sectionName){
    Criteria criteira=Criteria.where("sections.srcName").in(sectionName);
    return match(criteira);
}

private  GroupOperation getGroupOperaion(){
    return  group().addToSet("sections.data.values.srcDesc").as("srcDescs");
}

public List<String> findAllSrcDescBySection(String sectionName){
    MatchOperation matchOperation=getMatchOperation(sectionName);
    GroupOperation groupOperation=getGroupOperaion();
    BasicDBObject aggregationResults=
               mongoTemplate.aggregate(Aggregation.newAggregation(
                       matchOperation,
                       unwind("sections"),
                       unwind("sections.data"),
                       unwind("sections.data.values"),
                       matchOperation,
                       groupOperation), collectionname, BasicDBObject.class).getUniqueMappedResult();
   return (ArrayList)aggregationResults.get("srcDescs");
}
```

Update 3.4 version:

This is similar to above but instead of `$unwind'ing`,  we are `$reduce'ing` to `$project` `srcDescs` from each document.

`$map + $filter` to filter the `sections` elements with input `srcName` followed by map to transform the output. `$reduce` will use the output from filter stage inside the map stage to extract and merge ( `$concatArrays` part) `srcDesc` across all `values` in each `data`.

`$unwind + $group` to get distinct  `srcDesc` with `$addToSet` operator.

```
aggregate([{
        $project: {
            srcDescs: {
                $arrayElemAt: [{
                    $map: {
                        input: {
                            $filter: {
                                input: "$sections",
                                as: "sectionsf",
                                cond: {
                                    $eq: ["$$sectionsf.srcName", "test1"]
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        as: "sectionsm",
                        in: {
                            $reduce: {
                                input: "$$sectionsm.data",
                                initialValue: [],
                                in: {
                                    $concatArrays: ["$$value", "$$this.values.srcDesc"]
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }, 0]
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $unwind: "$srcDescs"
    },
    {
        $group: {
            _id: null,
            srcDescs: {
                $addToSet: "$srcDescs"
            }
        }
    }
])
```

Comment: @ Veeram , Thank you. I will try this today. Also, I am new to all this. Do you have any links to good documentation that can help me on these unwind concept or addtoSet concept.

Comment: You are welcome. Here are links https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/addToSet/ & https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/. You can improve your aggregation pipeline if you are on mongo server 3.4 version. Let me know what version you are on and I can update the answer.

Comment: Yes . We are at db version v3.4.3. Appreciate your help on this.

Comment: You are welcome. Please try to test the current changes and will try to update changes for 3.4

Comment: Unfortunately the results did provided me with unique results. May be we are missing something here. Below is the out put

Comment: Sorry, I had a typo. The solution worked. Now , i need to understand it properly how it worked.

Comment: Np. Please feel free to ask if you have any questions and I can add more details. Also, I've added 3.4 mongo shell query. See if you can convert it to spring equivalent.